# Shrink monospaced font in custom (verbatim) environments

Tags: fonts, verbatim, mdframed, microtype

I'm redesigning lecture notes for a university class since the students wanted to read the notes on their tablets, e-book readers, etc.

I have code blocks in these documents, defined in the `cdblk` and `codeblocks` environments. The `codeblocks` environment is a `verbatim` environment, while `cdblk` is not, but I need them both, since for example `\textquotesingle` doesn't display correctly in verbatim (that's what I use `cdblk` for).

I also have defined a `\paper` key in the preamble of the A4 paper version of the document, while in tablet versions I defined a `\tablet` key. I also have two commands `\ifpaper{}` and `\iftablet{}` for paper and tablet specific tex code.

I would like to adjust the font size the above mentioned `cdblk` and `codeblock` environments when a small paper size (`\iftablet{}`) is used like in the MWE below.

This is what I have tried so far, but neither of them work:

1. I've tried to use adjustbox around `cdblk` and `codeblock` environments, but I run into an error.

   ```
   ! Missing \endgroup inserted.
   <inserted text>
                   \endgroup
   l.61     \begin{codeblock}
   ```
2. I've tried to set monospaced font shrinkage with `microtype`, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. (Included in the MWE below.)

   ```
   \SetExpansion[shrink=100]{family=tt*}{}
   ```
3. I've tried to define different font size `cdblk` environments for the paper and tablet versions in the preamble using `\ifpaper{}` and `\iftablet{}`, but when I compile the document the compiler doesn't notice those definitions, so it thinks that the environment is not defined.

At least 72 characters should fit in the `cdblk` and `codeblock` environments with the smallest paper size I use (used in the MWE). Of course, fitting 80 characters would be better but I need 72 at least.

Here is the example minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt, titlepage]{article}

%\def\paper{1}
\def\tablet{1}

\usepackage[nohead,%
    nofoot,%
    nomarginpar,%
    paperwidth=106.68mm,%
    paperheight=142.24mm,%
    tmargin=2.5mm,%
    rmargin=2.5mm,%
    bmargin=2.5mm,%
    lmargin=2.5mm,
    vscale=1,%
    hscale=1]{geometry}
%\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[headings]{fullpage}

\newcommand{\ifpaper}[1]{\ifx\paper\undefined\else{#1}\fi}
\newcommand{\iftablet}[1]{\ifx\tablet\undefined\else{#1}\fi}

\usepackage[cmyk, pdftex]{xcolor}

\definecolor{PMS420}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 0.15}

\usepackage[protrusion=true,%
    expansion=true]{microtype}

\SetExpansion[shrink=100]{family=tt*}{}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz,%
    innerleftmargin=\parindent,%
    skipabove=0.4\baselineskip,%
    skipbelow=0.4\baselineskip,%
    innertopmargin=0.4\baselineskip,%
    innerbottommargin=0.4\baselineskip]{mdframed}

\newmdenv[linewidth=0pt,%
    linecolor=PMS420,%
    backgroundcolor=PMS420,%
    settings={\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}}]{cdblk}
\newenvironment{codeblock}{\endgraf\verbatim}{\endverbatim}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{codeblock}{\begin{cdblk}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{codeblock}{\end{cdblk}}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{cdblk}
\verb+80 characters should                      fit in                        one line+
\end{cdblk}

\begin{codeblock}
80 characters should                      fit in                        one line
\end{codeblock}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this one help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142394/listings-font-size-that-fits-80-columns

Comment: @egreg It did, thank you! However I had to decrease the number of iterations from 80 to 72 to fit 80 characters in one line, but I don't know why. Also could you please post this as an answer, so I can accept your answer and give you the credit. (I only had to replace `\lstset{basicstyle=\fontsize{\eightytt}{1.2\eightytt}\ttfamily}` with `cdblk`'s and `codeblock`'s definition and added `font=\fontsize{\eightytt}{1.2\eightytt}\ttfamily` to its definition.)

Comment: You could also just add the font size commands to the settings key of your `newmdenv`.  Using plain tex conditionals, if you have `\newif\ifsmall` and `\smalltrue` then `settings={\ifsmall\fontsize{6pt}{7pt}\selectfont\fi...` would do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding the answer egreg pointed me to ([listings font size that fits 80 columns?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142394/listings-font-size-that-fits-80-columns)). I like this because it will select the font size according to the page size (more precisely to `\textwidth`), so I can use this with all paper sizes I work with, resulting that 80 characters will fit into `cdblk` or `codeblock` environments.

All I had to do is to replace `cdblk`'s and `codeblock`'s definition with:

```
\newlength{\eightytt}

\newcommand{\testthewidth}{%
    \fontsize{\dimen0}{0}\selectfont%
    \sbox0{x\global\dimen1=0.6em}%
    \ifdim 73\dimen1>\textwidth%
        \advance\dimen0 by -.1pt%
        \expandafter\testthewidth%
    \else%
        \global\eightytt\dimen0%
    \fi%
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \dimen0=\csname f@size\endcsname pt%
    \begingroup%
    \ttfamily%
    \testthewidth%
    \endgroup%
    \newmdenv[font=\fontsize{\eightytt}{1.2\eightytt}\ttfamily,%
        linewidth=0pt,%
        linecolor=PMS420,%
        backgroundcolor=PMS420,%
        settings={\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}}]{cdblk}
        \newenvironment{codeblock}{\endgraf\verbatim}{\endverbatim}
        \BeforeBeginEnvironment{codeblock}{\begin{cdblk}}
        \AfterEndEnvironment{codeblock}{\end{cdblk}}
}
```

Fully working example:

[image: answer]

```
\documentclass[10pt, titlepage]{article}

%\def\paper{1}
\def\tablet{1}

\usepackage[nohead,%
    nofoot,%
    nomarginpar,%
    paperwidth=106.68mm,%
    paperheight=142.24mm,%
    tmargin=2.5mm,%
    rmargin=2.5mm,%
    bmargin=2.5mm,%
    lmargin=2.5mm,
    vscale=1,%
    hscale=1]{geometry}
%\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[headings]{fullpage}

\newcommand{\ifpaper}[1]{\ifx\paper\undefined\else{#1}\fi}
\newcommand{\iftablet}[1]{\ifx\tablet\undefined\else{#1}\fi}

\usepackage[cmyk, pdftex]{xcolor}

\definecolor{PMS420}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 0.15}

\usepackage[protrusion=true,%
    expansion=true]{microtype}

\SetExpansion[shrink=100]{family=tt*}{}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz,%
    innerleftmargin=\parindent,%
    skipabove=0.4\baselineskip,%
    skipbelow=0.4\baselineskip,%
    innertopmargin=0.4\baselineskip,%
    innerbottommargin=0.4\baselineskip]{mdframed}

\pagestyle{empty}

% egreg's solution:
\newlength{\eightytt}

\newcommand{\testthewidth}{%
    \fontsize{\dimen0}{0}\selectfont%
    \sbox0{x\global\dimen1=0.6em}%
    \ifdim 73\dimen1>\textwidth%
        \advance\dimen0 by -.1pt%
        \expandafter\testthewidth%
    \else%
        \global\eightytt\dimen0%
    \fi%
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \dimen0=\csname f@size\endcsname pt%
    \begingroup%
    \ttfamily%
    \testthewidth%
    \endgroup%
    \newmdenv[font=\fontsize{\eightytt}{1.2\eightytt}\ttfamily,%
        linewidth=0pt,%
        linecolor=PMS420,%
        backgroundcolor=PMS420,%
        settings={\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}}]{cdblk}
        \newenvironment{codeblock}{\endgraf\verbatim}{\endverbatim}
        \BeforeBeginEnvironment{codeblock}{\begin{cdblk}}
        \AfterEndEnvironment{codeblock}{\end{cdblk}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{cdblk}
\verb+80 characters should                      fit in                        one line+
\end{cdblk}

\begin{codeblock}
80 characters should                      fit in                        one line
\end{codeblock}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

One possible way to do this would be to create a new conditional and then add a font size switch to the settings key of your `newmdenv`.

```
\newif\ifsmall
\smalltrue    % we want small sizes
%\smallfalse  % uncomment to turn off small sizes
\newmdenv[linewidth=0pt, linecolor=PMS420, backgroundcolor=PMS420,%
    settings={\ifsmall\fontsize{6pt}{7pt}\selectfont\fi\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}}]{cdblk}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[10pt, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}

\newcommand*\verbfont{%
  \fontfamily{lmtt}\fontseries{lc}\fontshape{n}\selectfont%
  \SetTracking{encoding=*}{-50}\lsstyle}
%\def\paper{1}
\def\tablet{1}

\usepackage[nohead,%
    nofoot,%
    nomarginpar,%
    paperwidth=106.68mm,%
    paperheight=142.24mm,%
    tmargin=2.5mm,%
    rmargin=2.5mm,%
    bmargin=2.5mm,%
    lmargin=2.5mm,
    vscale=1,%
    hscale=1]{geometry}
%\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[headings]{fullpage}

\newcommand{\ifpaper}[1]{\ifx\paper\undefined\else{#1}\fi}
\newcommand{\iftablet}[1]{\ifx\tablet\undefined\else{#1}\fi}

\usepackage[cmyk, pdftex]{xcolor}
\definecolor{PMS420}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 0.15}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@font{\verbfont\setbox0=\hbox{1}\fontdimen2\font=\the\wd0}
\makeatother

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz,%
    innerleftmargin=\parindent,%
    skipabove=0.4\baselineskip,%
    skipbelow=0.4\baselineskip,%
    innertopmargin=0.4\baselineskip,%
    innerbottommargin=0.4\baselineskip]{mdframed}
\newmdenv[linewidth=0pt,%
    linecolor=PMS420,%
    backgroundcolor=PMS420,%
    settings={\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}}]{cdblk}
\newenvironment{codeblock}{\endgraf\verbatim}{\endverbatim}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{codeblock}{\begin{cdblk}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{codeblock}{\end{cdblk}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{cdblk}
\verb+80 characters should                      fit in                        one line+
\end{cdblk}

\begin{codeblock}
80 characters should                      fit in                        one line
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
\end{codeblock}

{\verbfont
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789}

\ttfamily
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
\end{document}
```

The `\fontdimen2\font` controls the width between two words. It must be set to the width of a character of the mono font, e.g. the "1" as seen above.

[image]